# what does "payout" mean

Tags: terminology

From Smart Cities by Anthony M. Townsend:

> Finding growth opportunities has become a constant struggle for Cisco,
>   and to make a dent on the bottom line it needs to have billion-dollar
>   payouts.

What does "payouts" mean? 
Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it means revenue generated by a specific product or service. The quote occurs in the context of describing Cisco'S ambitions of becoming "the new plumber of smart cities", which means large-scale public and private infrastructure projects - certainly the kind of thing where you can earn a few billion dollars in aggregate.